# Is it possible to store the reference from a dynamically called function that *returns* by reference in PHP 5?

Tags: php, reference

In PHP 5, is there any way to *dynamically* (i.e. via the use of `call_user_func` or `ReflectionFunction::invoke()`) call a function that **returns** by reference, and store the reference it returned, without raising a notice/warning/error, and without using error control operators (`@`)?

**I am NOT** referring to *passing* by reference. [Returning by reference](http://php.net/language.references.return) is a completely different topic.

To illustrate:

```
$a = (object) array();

$callback = function & () use (&$a) {
    return $a;
};

// no problems, and sure enough $b === $a    
$b = &$callback();

// emits "Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference"
// but still $b === $a anyway
$b = &call_user_func($callback);
```

Comment: This is well-explained [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php).

Do you have a more realistic use-case?

Comment: It seems to be a limitation of `call_user_func()`. Why do you need to use `call_user_func()`?

Comment: @Will I am familiar with the linked reference, but it does not mention anything about *dynamic* (i.e. `call_user_*()`) usage. The use case is complicated. I have written a mocking framework (http://lqnt.co/phony), and I'm trying to improve support for return-by-reference methods. I want to determine if there's any way for me to retain references returned by the code under test, whilst retaining all the functionality of a mocking framework, which requires the code under test to be called dynamically via `call_user_func_array()`.

Comment: What about just setting a variable `$funcname` to the name of the function, and calling it like `$ref = &$funcname();`? This is mentioned in the comments of the `call_user_func()` docs.

Comment: @Will That's a good idea. Unfortunately in my use case, I cannot know the number of arguments ahead of time. Regardless of how many arguments a mocked method is defined with, it can be called with additional arguments at run-time. The only way I can think of to apply your solution would involve dynamically building the argument list by inspecting the result of `func_get_args()`, and use of `eval()`. That's quite complicated, and would negatively impact the performance of calling a mocked method.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this seems to be a non-issue for PHP 7: https://3v4l.org/msaIZ

Comment: Ah, I see. Okay, what about variable function names and varadic call syntax (PHP 5.6+)? `&$funcname(...$argsArray);`

Comment: Sounds like a good solution for >= 5.6. This library currently targets >= 5.3, which rules that out also. I'm fairly certain that a solution for my particular use case does not exist. However, if you'd like to put together an answer with your suggestions so far, I'd be happy to accept, because they do solve the original question.

Comment: Alright, I summed this up into an answer :) I also wrote out a possible `eval()` solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is no way to make `call_user_func()` return a reference in PHP 5.x. However, depending on the PHP version, there may be some workarounds.

One approach seems to work:

```
$b = &$callback();
```

As we discussed in the comments, this presents a problem when we have to call `$callback()` with a configured/variable number of arguments. If we have PHP 5.6, there is a workaround, with the [`...` (splat) operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking):

```
$b = &$callback(...$argArray);
```

This will unpack the arguments contained in `$argArray` sequentially, and pass them as function arguments to `$callback()`.

Unfortunately, this will only work in PHP 5.6+.

Before PHP 5.6, you're probably stuck using something like this (untested):

```
$argsToEval = array_map(function($key) {
    return '$argArray[' . $key . ']';
}, array_keys($argArray));

$code = sprintf('$b = &$callback(%s);', implode(', ', $argsToEval);
eval($code);
```

We can both agree that this is messy. But, perhaps, different syntax could be used depending on the PHP version, as you indicated that you need to support 5.3+. I would also encourage you to drop 5.3 and 5.4 support, as 5.3 hit End of Life in March 2013, and 5.4 hit End of Life in September 2015. 5.5 will hit End of Life in June of this year. But, I do realize the practicalities of some users being able to upgrade, even once EoL has passed.